# PHPStorm missing return statement

Tags: php, phpstorm

This function

```
public function confirmation() {
  if (is_array($this->modules)) {
    if (isset($GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]) && 
        is_object($GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]) && 
        ($GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]->enabled)) {
      return $GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]->confirmation();
    }
  }
}
```

gives the notice

> Missing return statement

Is there any solution to get the return outside of the brackets?

Comment: Hi Ronny. Did any of the below answers solve your question? If yes, could you mark the most helpful answer as accepted by clicking the arrow. It stops others trying to solve an already solved question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have here is a single `return` inside a conditional. If the conditional is not satisfied then execution will reach the end of the function without hitting a `return` statement, which is equivalent to `return null`.

Therefore, one thing you can do is make the `return null` explicit:

```
if (...) {
    return $GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]->confirmation();
}
else {
    // Can also do this without an "else", it's a matter of style
    return null;
}
```

You could also move the conditional into the return value expression by using the ternary operator:

```
return is_array($this->modules) &&
       isset($GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]) && 
       is_object($GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]) && 
       $GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]->enabled)
       ? $GLOBALS[$this->selected_module]->confirmation()
       : null
```

However, this is arguably too much for a ternary operator to gracefully handle, so readability is perhaps an issue here.

Comment: You're right. With your explanation I get it and it's also logical.

Comment: Just to add - I would avoid the `else` to have a bit more readable code.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to have multiple return statements in a single function.

Decide how your code should behave if things aren't set properly and put a default return statement at the end of the function.  Or raise an exception if it is a full blown error condition that should never happen.